# Rails and Bluepill, how to monitor sub processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have bluepill setup to spawn and monitor delayed_job processes. I have bluepill monitoring CPU usage at the moment. The jobs that I queue onto Delayed Job workers are for creating thumbnails from videos using ffmpeg.

I'd like bluepill to monitor not just the delayed job worker, but also it's child process. I don't think this is default behavior, and I'm aware of using process.monitor_children. The rails method that's queued into Delayed Job calls ffmpeg using the system() command. Would delayed job be able to monitor that'?